# jQuery file upload POST data append issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js

I am using jQuery file uploader in my **Backbone** application.

> I am facing problem in POST data i.e when I upload data then only file
>   which is selected will be added in **POST object** and one **id** which is
>   initialized in **initializeFileUpload function in formData** and this initializeFileUpload function is load in **OnLoad**

**this.ui.uploadAppFile** is jquery object

```
initializeFileUpload: function() {
                var that = this,
                    file = "";
                var options = {
                    url: FSGlobals.baseURL + 'requests/req_bu_files/file',
                    maxFileSize: 5000000, // 5MB
                    formData: {
                      "Id": that.requestHeaderMod.get("id"),
                     },
                    add: function(e, data) {
                        file = (data && data.files[0] && data.files[0].name) || "";
                        that.manualPostData = data;
                        that.ui.filePlaceholder.val(file).change();
                    }
                };

                if ($('html').hasClass('ie9') || $('html').hasClass('lt-ie9')) {
                    options.forceIframeTransport = true;
                } else {
                    options.dataType = 'json';
                }

                this.ui.uploadAppFile.fileupload(options);
            }
```

I have one button **Submit** and at submit time ***I have to add two more id's in Post Object.***

```
UploadAction: function() {
                var that = this;
                this.manualPostData.submit().
                done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                    })
                    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                    });
               }
```

Now I try to find formData in **this.manualPostData** but I can't find **formData** in it.

> After Submit I see in Network it's showing  formData object with file[] and Id which is declared in
>   initializeFileUpload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found One solution:**

> Before **submit** pass your values to **formData**. But as you can
>   see in question there is one more method  i.e **initializeFileUpload**
>   you have to initialize your file up-loader setting and all stuff.
>   because if not then at submit time you dont get
>   **this.manualPostData** As file up-loader object

```
UploadAction: function() {

            var that = this;
            this.manualPostData.formData = {
                "requestId": that.requestHeaderMod.get("id"),
                "status": false,
                "appId": this.ui.appListSelect.select2("val"),
                "appDimensionId": this.ui.appDimListSelect.select2("val"),
                "actionCode": this.ui.actionCodeSelect.select2("val")
            }
            this.manualPostData.submit()
           .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                   //
            })
            .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    //Fail

            });
```

And pass Formdata={} in initializeFileUpload other wise you have to use

```
$.extend(OLd Object, New Object);
```

at submit time

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you can use the method submit to add additional values to the request:

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#submit

Here is a fiddle I created to demonstrate how the method can be overridden.

https://jsfiddle.net/LtzvL6s9/

```
submit: function(e, data) {
  console.log('submit',data, data.formData)
  data.formData = $.extend({}, {'other': 2}, data.formData);
}
```

I have not been able to send the original id and then append additional data to the form, but you can add everything you need on the submit method.

Hope this helps to solve your issue.