# AJAX Fileupload with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I am currently trying to solve a problem.
I have several forms on a single page which get sent to the backend asynchronously via ajax.

Now some of them need to have a fileupload which doesnt break the process, so it alsoneeds to be handled asynchronously.

I am trying to figure it out like that :

```
// Allgemein Submit
    $allgSubmit.click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        var gehrKundennummer = $('#gehrKundennummer').val();
        var kundenklasse = $("input[type='radio'][name='kundenklasse']:checked").val();
        var lkw12t = $('#lkw12t').val();
        var lkw3t = $('#lkw3t').val();
        var autobus = $('#autobus').val();
        var firmenname1 = $('#firmenname1').val();
        var firmenname2 = $('#firmenname2').val();
        var uidnummer = $('#uidnummer').val();
        var peselregon = $('#peselregon').val();
        var firmenart = $('#firmenart option:selected').val();
        var strasse = $('#strasse').val();
        var ort = $('#ort').val();
        var plz = $('#plz').val();
        var land = $('#land').val();
        var fd = new FormData();
        var file = fd.append('file', $('#allg_firmen_dok').get(0).files[0]);

        var allgArray = { 
            'gehrKundennummer':gehrKundennummer, 
            'kundenklasse':kundenklasse,
            'lkw12t':lkw12t,
            'lkw3t':lkw3t,
            'autobus':autobus,
            'firmenname1':firmenname1,
            'firmenname2':firmenname2,
            'uidnummer':uidnummer,
            'peselregon':peselregon,
            'firmenart':firmenart,
            'strasse':strasse,
            'ort':ort,
            'plz':plz,
            'land':land,
            'file':file
        };

        //var data = new FormData();
        //jQuery.each(jQuery('#allg_firmen_dok')[0].files, function(i, file) {
          // data.append('file-'+i, file);
        //});

        console.log(allgArray);
        $.ajax({
            url: "PATHTOFILE/logic/logic_update_client_allg.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: allgArray,
            processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
            contentType: false,
            success: function(allgArray){
                alert(allgArray);
                var allgSave = $('#allgSave');
                allgSave.text('Aktualisieren erfolgreich!');
                allgSave.toggle();
            },
            error: function(){
                var allgSave = $('#allgSave');
                allgSave.text('Aktualisieren fehlgeschlagen!');
                allgSave.toggle();
            }
        });
    });
```

The console log of the array returns all values correctly except the one for "file"
it says undefined.

I don't know how to deal with it, are there any requirements that im missing?

Thanks for any kind of help

**EDIT**

```
var file = fd.append('file', $('#allg_firmen_dok').get(0).files[0]);
```

returns undefined

Comment: Did you send file to your path before do that click?

Comment: I don't exactly know what you mean? The operation flow is as follows: SUBMIT CLICK -> getting values of all input fields -> getting FILE -> putting in array -> sending to php

Comment: I think `fd.append()` executes correctly, then returns `undefined`. It just appends stuff to `fd`. So you're assigning `undefined` to the `file` variable. Just drop the file variable and keep using fd.

Comment: If you are using jquery file uploader then in add: function call back you get data so get that data and store in global variable. I am using same thing it works for me..                                                                                                                          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30283970/jquery-file-upload-post-data-append-issue

Comment: @JeremyThille I tried out to pass fd to the array, but even after appending something to fd , fd still results : FormData {append: function}

Answer (score 0):

I think the variable fd = new FormData() is an Object and it has attribute "file". So it cannot pass the attribute "file" to another Object "allgArray"
You need to check about it before you call function

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "PATHTOFILE/logic/logic_update_client_allg.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: allgArray,
```

Think about the data you send! It maybe another instance to get data from "file" of "fd". Hope it help you! ^^
Btw, I used AJAX to send file last time

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
$("#Form").on('submit',(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "uploader.php", // Url to which the request is send
        type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
        data: new FormData(this), // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
        contentType: false,       // The content type used when sending data to the server.
        cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
        processData:false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
        success: function(data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
        {
             console.log(data);
        }
    });
}));
```

});

Comment: Thanks for your help, apparently I can't refer to the instance of FormData as "this" as this returns my submit button.
So "file" remains undefined

Answer (score 0):

add `headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }` in ajax option

Comment: the problem occurs earlier, before sending the data with ajax actually. 
When I try to log the allgArray -> the index "file" remains undefined